# Shortest path (point to point) in iteration

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, iteration, shortest-path

I am using Network Analysis-> Shortest path (point to point) to compute the distance between two points, following a network from OSM. It works like magic for single requests, but I do not seem to be able to make it work in an iteration. The script is as follows:

```
import processing
import csv

with open('.../Locations.csv', "r") as Tele_points:
    TeleLoc=list(csv.reader(Tele_points, delimiter=','))
    for line in TeleLoc:
        x=line[2]
        y=line[3]
        location=y+','+x
        x1=line[10]
        y1=line[11]
        location1=y1+','+x1

        processing.run("native:shortestpathpointtopoint", {'INPUT':'...\\OSM_Net.shp|layername=OSM_Net','STRATEGY':0,'DIRECTION_FIELD':None,'VALUE_FORWARD':'','VALUE_BACKWARD':'','VALUE_BOTH':'','DEFAULT_DIRECTION':2,'SPEED_FIELD':None,'DEFAULT_SPEED':50,'TOLERANCE':0,'START_POINT':''+location+'','END_POINT':''+location1+'','OUTPUT':'.../Path.shp'})
```

This script overwrites the output shapefile and I would like to have it appended instead so that the results of each pair of locations can be on a different line in the attribute table.

Comment: A fast workaround answer : increments an integer like `i` and create `'OUTPUT':'.../Path' + i + '.shp'` and finally, merge all shapefiles.

Comment: Yeah, I also considered that option, but I really want to avoid it as I am working on hundreds of location pairs at a time.

Comment: It's possible to save the result into a PostGIS table, I think it append the result (but it's only available if you have a PostgreSQL database installed).

Comment: Thanks again. I decided to go for quick and dirty and used your fist suggestion. Deleting unnecessary files was a long journey, but managed to overcome it. Cheers